# Displaying day of week

Tags: datepicker, mobiscroll

Is there a way to display the day of week (short or long) in the picker itself?  I've seen examples of this value getting calculated but I've found nothing that shows a picker that resembles to IOS one where the left most wheel shows the day of the week AND the day of the month...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `dateOrder` option, where you would need to pass: `'mmD ddy'`

It will look something like

```
$('#demo').mobiscroll().date({
    // your inti properties
    dateOrder: 'mmD ddy'
});
```